# How to create a mat-progress bar after showing a dialog box

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material, angular7

I have a page in which I have a Run button.If I click on Run button a dialog box appears with two options Yes and No.If a user clicks Yes I want to display a mat-progress bar.
I am confused as to where to write the html code of mat-progress bar and where to call it from.

HTML Code:

```
<mat-toolbar>
                        <div class="col-md-offset-11">
                            <button
                                mat-raised-button
                                mat-hint="Execute Query on Whole DataSet"
                                color="primary"
                                (click)="executeOnFullData()"
                            >
                                Run
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </mat-toolbar>
```

TypeScript Code:

```
    executeOnFullData() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmJobRunComponent, {
    });

    dialogRef.afterClosed()
}
```

HTML Code for dialogBox:

```
<div class="card">
<div class="card-header"><h5 class="title">Confirm</h5></div>
<div class="content">
    <h3 mat-dialog-title>
        Are you sure you want to run Recommendation Settings on the entire
        Dataset?
    </h3>

    <div mat-dialog-actions>
        <button
            mat-button
            [mat-dialog-close]="true"
            (click)="confirmSelection()"
        >
            Yes
        </button>
        <button mat-button (click)="onNoClick()">
            Cancel
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Typescript Code for DialogComponent

```
import { MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef } from "@angular/material";
import { Component, Inject } from "@angular/core";
import { RecommendationService } from "../../recommendation- 
service.service";

@Component({
selector: "app-confirm-job-run",
templateUrl: "./confirm-job-run.component.html",
styleUrls: ["./confirm-job-run.component.scss"]
})
export class ConfirmJobRunComponent {
constructor(
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<ConfirmJobRunComponent>,
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
    public dataService: RecommendationService
) {}

onNoClick(): void {
    this.dialogRef.close();
}

confirmSelection(): void {}
}
```

Comment: show us what you've tried

Comment: I am trying to create a stackblitz.Actual code is too long.Please check the question I have updated it

Comment: Where are you trying to show the `mat-progress` bar? In the dialog?

Comment: No, on click of Run button i show a dialog box with two options Yes and No.If the user clicks Yes then I want to show dialog box on the screen where Run button is placed.(Let's call it screen 1 and dialog box as screen 2)

Comment: So you want a second dialog to open up after the first? I am a bit confused by what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: lets call the run button screen1 and dialog box as screen 2.If i click on screen 1 run button a dialog box pops up and ask whether you want to run the job. If i click no then i return to screen 1 and if i click on yes i return to screen1 again but this time a mat-progress bar is placed on top of screen which shows a job is running

Comment: And the `mat-progress` would be shown on screen 1 once the dialog has been closed?

Comment: @FabianKüng Yes the mat-progress will be shown when dialog box is closed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just subscribe to `afterClosed` of your `dialogRef` and based on the result you get back from your dialog (clicking Yes returns `true`, clicking No returns `false`) you can then show a `mat-progress` and execute your business logic.

> [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/am-all-imports-c44xbv?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)
>   is a stackblitz showing how this could look like. The `mat-progress`
>   is currently indeterminate and not waiting for something to complete,
>   that is up to you.

Template (in your component where the button is located)

```
<mat-progress-bar *ngIf="showMatProgress" mode="indeterminate"></mat-progress-bar>
```

Component for above template

```
showMatProgress: boolean = false;

executeOnFullData() {
  const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ConfirmJobRunComponent, {});

  dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result) => {
    this.showMatProgress = result;
  });
}
```

An in your dialog component

```
onNoClick(): void {
  this.dialogRef.close(false);
}

confirmSelection(): void {
  this.dialogRef.close(true);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain me how this result works in subscribe.dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((result)

Comment: It is what you pass to the close() function in the dialog component. You can pass any object you like and access it in afterClosed().

Comment: Can you help me with greying out whole screen while the progress bar is running. How do i disable touch and click on screen while progress bar is executing.

Comment: This would be something for a new question, but have a look at the Angular Material documentation of [CDK Overlay](https://material.angular.io/cdk/overlay/overview), this should get you started.